# Flask upload files successfully but can't find the uploaded file on the server

Tags: python, file-upload, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I use Flask to upload files to a server, while I was uploading, nothing went wrong and there were not any bugs either, once the file was uploaded, the database was also modified, but when the upload finished, I clicked on the file link to find that no corresponding file on the server so the downloading process failed.

Actually, there was a judgment after uploading, only when the file saved successfully success that it would write the database, but now the result turned out to be opposite,so I don't know where it went wrong. Can somebody have a look?

#### Upload file and write the database:

```
status = upload_file(curr_upload, upload_path, ['wrap', 'pdf'])
if status[0]:
    homework_upload = HomeworkUpload(name=homework_file_name, homework_id=hid, user_id=current_user.id, uri=homework_uri)
    db.session.add(homework_upload)
    cur_homework.uploads.append(homework_upload)

    db.session.commit()
    upload_ids.append(homework_upload.id)
    upload_names.append(homework_upload.name)
    upload_uris.append(homework_upload.uri)
    upload_times.append(datetime.strftime(homework_upload.submit_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
```

#### my upload file function:

```
def upload_file(file_src, des_path, allowed_type=None):
if file_src.filename == '':
    message = gettext('No selected file')
    return False, message

extension = file_src.filename[file_src.filename.rfind('.')+1:]
file_type = extension_to_file_type(extension)
folder = des_path[:des_path.rfind('/')]

if not allowed_type:
    allowed_type = current_app.config['ALLOWED_RESOURCE_TYPE']

if file_src and '.' in file_src.filename and file_type in allowed_type:
    if not os.path.exists(folder):
        os.makedirs(folder)
    file_src.save(des_path)
    unique_uri = os.stat(des_path).st_mtime
    if os.path.exists(des_path):
        return True, unique_uri
    else:
        message = gettext("Save File Failed!")
        return False, message
else:
    message = gettext("Invalid file")
    return False, message
```

#### Environment

- Python version: 2.7.14
- Flask version: 0.11.1